# Another "OnLocationChanged callback is never called"

Tags: android, geolocation, google-api-client, locationmanager

Since this is a typical question, asked so many times - yes, I've checked them all already.

This is how I init:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

This is how I connect/disconnect:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Debugging it, I see that this is called:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    Timber.i("onConnected");

}
```

Later down the road, this gets called as well:

```
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);

    mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

But none of these are ever called:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Timber.i("onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Timber.w("onConnectionFailed");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Timber.d("onLocationChanged " + location);
    mLastKnownLocation = location;
    moveCamToCurrentLocation();
}
```

On my friend's device it works, and it used to work on mine, too.
I do checkSelfPermission() etc. and also checked Advanced Settings of my phone, Maps works.... Am I experiencing an evil unmanageable bug? I'm out of ideas. Btw, here is an excerpt of my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

The device displays a GoogleMap, and I do get a valid location at this line, too:

```
    mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Am I missing something? Does anyone have a clue for me please?

Comment: I hope this will help:  https://gist.github.com/ayeshq/05f1f83b7083708212dfb6b64e7eb5f2

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful actually. Btw, everything works fine now - without any changes on the code! It works as expected, all I did was change my location. Earlier I was sitting in *that* building, now I'm sitting in *this* building and I get regular location updates. just how can I make a reliable app?